# Neo4j Cypher - counting occurrences of two independent patterns in 1 query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

**Question:** how do I count the occurrence of two independent patterns in a single Cypher query *without using optional relationships*?

**Example:** for every person in a social network count how many friends they have and how many posts they've made.

With optional relationships it's easy...

Count persons' friends:

```
MATCH (person:PERSON)
WITH person
MATCH (person)-[?:KNOWS]-(friend:PERSON)
RETURN person.firstName AS name, count(friend) AS friends

+----------------------+
| name       | friends |
+----------------------+
| "alex"     | 3       |
| "aiya"     | 1       |
| "jacob"    | 1       |
| "peter"    | 1       |
| "stranger" | 0       |
+----------------------+
```

Count persons' posts:

```
MATCH (person:PERSON)
WITH person
MATCH (person)<-[?:HAS_CREATOR]-(post:POST)
RETURN person.firstName AS name, count(post) AS posts

+--------------------+
| name       | posts |
+--------------------+
| "alex"     | 0     |
| "aiya"     | 3     |
| "jacob"    | 3     |
| "peter"    | 1     |
| "stranger" | 2     |
+--------------------+
```

Count persons' friends and posts:

```
MATCH (person:PERSON)
WITH person
MATCH (person)-[?:KNOWS]-(friend:PERSON)
WITH person, count(friend) AS friends
MATCH (person)<-[?:HAS_CREATOR]-(post:POST)
RETURN person.firstName AS name, friends, count(post) AS posts

+------------------------------+
| name       | friends | posts |
+------------------------------+
| "peter"    | 1       | 1     |
| "aiya"     | 1       | 3     |
| "alex"     | 3       | 0     |
| "stranger" | 0       | 2     |
| "jacob"    | 1       | 3     |
+------------------------------+
```

**However**, without optional relationships the query result excludes all nodes that had a zero count result in either of the two `MATCH` clauses:

```
MATCH (person:PERSON)-[:KNOWS]-(friend:PERSON)
WITH person, count(friend) AS friends
MATCH (person)<-[:HAS_CREATOR]-(post:POST)
RETURN person.firstName AS name, friends, count(post) AS posts

+---------------------------+
| name    | friends | posts |
+---------------------------+
| "peter" | 1       | 1     |
| "aiya"  | 1       | 3     |
| "jacob" | 1       | 3     |
+---------------------------+
```

FYI, the desired result is:

```
+---------------------------+
| name    | friends | posts |
+---------------------------+
| "alex"  | 3       | 0     |
| "peter" | 1       | 1     |
| "aiya"  | 1       | 3     |
| "jacob" | 1       | 3     |
+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the use case for the optional relationships. Without the optional `?:KNOWS` to match to, you are saying to cypher "I want to match only those people who have a :KNOWS relationship to another person. Return them along with the number of relationships." And this, based on the MATCH you asked for, correctly excludes those without a :KNOWS relationship.

By adding the relationship as optional via the `?:KNOWS`, you are asking cypher: "Please get me all people and match them to other people using the :KNOWS relationship, if they have one. Return all people and count their friends."

Can you explain why you cannot use the optional relationship to do the matching in this case since it appears to me to be the exact tool for this job?

Comment: Hi @Edward, this was more of an exercise in curiosity than anything else. The example I gave is the most trivial I could think of, but there are more complex cases where the independent patterns are longer, and optional relationships more difficult to apply.